# Extract string between two substrings in a pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following dataframe:

```
                                           contract
0  Future(conId=482048803, symbol='ESTX50', lastT...
1  Future(conId=497000453, symbol='XT', lastTrade...
2  Stock(conId=321100413, symbol='SXRS', exchange...
3  Stock(conId=473087271, symbol='ETHEEUR', excha...
4  Stock(conId=80268543, symbol='IJPA', exchange=...
5  Stock(conId=153454120, symbol='EMIM', exchange...
6  Stock(conId=75776072, symbol='SXR8', exchange=...
7  Stock(conId=257200855, symbol='EGLN', exchange...
8  Stock(conId=464974581, symbol='VBTC', exchange...
9  Future(conId=478135706, symbol='ZN', lastTrade...
```

I want to create a new "symbol" column with all symbols (ESTX50, XT, SXRS...).

In order to extract the substring between "symbol='" and the following single quote, I tried the following:

```
df['symbol'] = df.contract.str.extract(r"symbol='(.*?)'")
```

but I get a column of NaN.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that is a column of objects, not strings:

```
import pandas as pd


class Future:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Future(symbol=\'{self.symbol}\')'


df = pd.DataFrame({'contract': [Future(symbol='ESTX50'), Future(symbol='XT')]})

df['symbol'] = df.contract.str.extract(r"symbol='(.*?)'")
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                  contract symbol
0  Future(symbol='ESTX50')    NaN
1      Future(symbol='XT')    NaN
```

Notice pandas considers strings to be `object` type so the string accessor is still allowed to attempt to perform operations. However, it cannot extract because these are not strings.

We can either convert to string first with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['symbol'] = df.contract.astype(str).str.extract(r"symbol='(.*?)'")
```

`df`:

```
                  contract  symbol
0  Future(symbol='ESTX50')  ESTX50
1      Future(symbol='XT')      XT
```

However, the faster approach is to try to extract the object property:

```
df['symbol'] = [getattr(x, 'symbol', None) for x in df.contract]
```

Or with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) (which can be slower than the comprehension)

```
df['symbol'] = df.contract.apply(lambda x: getattr(x, 'symbol', None))
```

Both produce:

```
                  contract  symbol
0  Future(symbol='ESTX50')  ESTX50
1      Future(symbol='XT')      XT
```